# Having issues with kpsewhich: "Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich"

Tags: ubuntu, latex

This is my GitHub Action Workflow.

name: Generate and Deploy Documentation

on:
push:
branches:
- main  # Replace with your branch name

jobs:
build-deploy:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: Checkout source code
uses: actions/checkout@v2

```
  - name: Set up Python
    uses: actions/setup-python@v2
    with:
      python-version: '3.9'

  - name: Install latexmk, zip, and cmap (dep for sphinx to generate PDFs and EPUBs)
    run: |
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get upgrade -y
      sudo apt-get install -y latexmk zip texmaker texlive texlive-extra-utils texlive-full
      type tex
      tlmgr conf
      wget https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
      sudo sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh -- --upgrade
      tlmgr update --self --all
      luaotfload-tool -fu
      tlmgr init-usertree
      tlmgr install cmap

  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      pip install sphinx sphinx_rtd_theme

  - name: Generate HTML documentation
    run: |
      cd docs
      make html
      make latexpdf
      mv ./build/latex/amadla.pdf ./amadla.pdf
      rm -rf ./build/latex/*
      mv ./amadla.pdf ./latex/amadla.pdf
      make epub
      zip -r amadla.epub ./build/epub/*
      rm -rf ./build/epub/*
      mv ./amadla.epub ./epub/amadla.epub

  - name: Checkout AmadlaOrg.github.io repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      repository: AmadlaOrg/AmadlaOrg.github.io
      token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT_DOC }}
      path: ./AmadlaOrg.github.io

  - name: Copy HTML documentation to AmadlaOrg.github.io repository
    run: |
      cp -r docs/build/* ./AmadlaOrg.github.io/docs

  - name: Commit and push changes
    run: |
      cd ./AmadlaOrg.github.io
      git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
      git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
      git add .
      if [ -n "$(git status --porcelain)" ]; then
        git commit -m "Update documentation"
        git push
      fi
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
2023-05-24 20:52:41 (4.35 MB/s) - ‘update-tlmgr-latest.sh’ saved [9441276/9441276]

Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater
     0%    44%    88%  100%  ./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
./runme.sh: (no tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb and/or tlpkg/tlpobj/.)
./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have tried different things.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, by why do you install texmaker in this action?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I saw it somewhere and I am trying anything to make it work. After it works I was planning to remove things one by one to keep things clean. I am basically throwing spaghetti on to the wall to see what sticks then cleaning up the spaghetti from the floor and keep whatever stayed on the wall.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. When you reach the clean-up phase, start with texmaker. It is just an editor and not necessary to compile tex documents.

Comment: Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I appreciate it. By the way have you ever used Latex in Ubuntu. On my local I have Kali Linux and everything runs well I am able to generate the PDF. But once it gets on Ubuntu of GitHub Workflows it goes poopoo.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with github actions, but what looks a bit fishy is that you are mixing the texlive from apt-get with vanilla stuff from tug.org. Personally I would only use the vanilla version from tug.org. The apt-get stuff is often outdated.  Maybe this action used by beamer can give you some inspiration? https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/main/.github/workflows/deploy.yaml#L38-L44